# Prove that for any natural $a$ there is a natural $b$ so that $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $a+b^2$ is not a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, coprime

Is there a **simple proof** of the following statement?

For any $a \in N$ exists such $b \in N$ that $a \perp b$ and $a + b^2$ is a composite number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick $b=2a+1$:
$$ a+(2a+1)^2 = (a+1)(4a+1). $$

Answer (score 1):

Any $b$ congruent to $1$ modulo $a+1$ will do the job. Such a $b$ will be of the form $k(a+1)+1=ka+(k+1)$, so any $k$ such that $k+1$ is coprime to $a$ will work, for example $k=a$.

In fact, for $k=a$ we get $b=a(a+1)+1$ and 
$$a+b^2=a+a^2(a+1)^2+2(a+1)+1=(a+1)+a^2(a+1)^2+2(a+1)=(a+1)(a^3+a^2+2a+1)$$

which is obviously divisible by $(a+1)$.

Comment: For $a=1$ you say that also $b=1$ will do the job? But $a+b^2=2$ is prime.

Comment: @DietrichBurde For $a=1$ my construction would lead to $b=3$.

Comment: No, I mean you say "Any $b$ congruent to $1$ modulo $a+1$ will do the job" in the first sentence. This is not true, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @DietrichBurde You're quite right - my mistake was assuming that $n\equiv 0\mod (a+1)$ implies $n$ is composite. It will work if we take $b$ (and thus $k$) sufficiently large.

Answer (score 0):

For $a>1$ odd we can take $b=1$. Then $a+b^2=a+1>2$ is even, hence not prime. In general, following Jack, one could also take $b=6a+1$. Then
$$
a+b^2=(9a+1)(4a+1).
$$